# (solved) Error "Tangled 0 code blocks from [file]"

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-babel

I'm writing a bash script with literate org-mode.

The header of the file is:

```
#+TITLE: start-lcs
#+AUTHOR: Stahlberg
#+EMAIL: stahl at gmail dot com
#+DATE: 2019-11-02
#+PROPERTY: header-args:sh :tangle "start-lcs.sh" :shebang "#!/bin/bash" :padline no :tangle-mode (identity #o755)
#+OPTIONS: author:t date:t email:t H:3 num:nil toc:t ^:{}
```

There are 50 blocks of code, one of them is:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh
  readonly EC_SUCCESS=0
  readonly EC_GENERIC=100
  readonly EC_PROGRAM_NOT_INSTALLED=101
  readonly EC_CANCEL_BUTTON_PRESSED=102
  readonly EC_NOT_YET_IMPLEMENTED=103
#+END_SRC
```

The file ends this way:

```
# @ Local variables:
# @ org-src-preserve-indentation: t
# @ End:
```

How come that when I tangle the file (`C-c C-v t`) Org-mode returns `Tangled 0 code blocks from start-lcs.org`?

Comment: Do you have include `:tangle yes` either as the source block header arguments or set in `org-babel-default-header-args`?

Comment: @Aquaactress there's `:tangle "start-lcs.sh"` in the `#+PROPERTY` section of the header.

Comment: I copied your text to a file and tried it. I couldn't get it to work unless I used `org-babel-default-header-args`. Not sure why this is. The manual seems to indicate that this is possible but it doesn't seem to be reading the `#+PROPERTY` section.

Comment: Solved! It was a single wrong keybinding in .emacs.d/init.el (not `C-c C-v t` nor one of Org-mode) that bugged all the Emacs configuration. Once corrected that keybinding Org-mode has begun to work as expected.